# SQL Convert 'yyyymmdd date' to 'mm/dd/yyyy' date

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, date, datetime, datetime-format

Thought I could use *convert(varchar(10),DateColumn,101)* like I do for most date to date conversions, but the output is the same as the input, yyyymmdd

Comment: Actually, this is probably a varchar column, not a datetime column.  So you'll need to convert it the other way around.

Comment: Consider whether this is a good idea. `yyyymmdd` is, in most ways, *better* than `mm/dd/yyyy`, which is ambiguous.

Comment: Persist dates values as a string is not a smart move. Try to use dates and datetimes types. In addition to @Keith comment you can get a hard time to implement localization example: mm/dd/yyyy is a US format but if you need to deploy app at UK it ill need to show and get input (at UI layer at least) as dd/mm/yyyy

Answer (score 3):

Here's a simple example that should answer your question:

```
    declare @date date
    set @date = '19901124'

    select @date --your date format
    select CONVERT(varchar(10), @date, 101)  --new date format
```

Hope that helps.

Thanks,
Matt

Answer (score 2):

```
declare @date varchar(8)
    set @date = '20151205'

SELECT convert(varchar(10), cast(@date AS date),103) -- dd/mm/aaaa
```

> 101 = mm/dd/aaaa
>
> 103 = dd/mm/aaaa
>
> 111 = aaaa/mm/dd

more info: https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-pe/library/ms187928.aspx